# elementwise multiplication between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = [['aaa', 1, 110, 2, 0],
        ['bbb', 0, 123, 10, 11],
        ['ccc', 0, 134, 1, 2],
        ['ddd', 1, 333, 2, 3],
        ['eee', 1, 444, 2, 0]]

data2 = [['Average', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
         ['Mean', 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
         ['denom', 0.3, 0.35, 0.4]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['user', 'A', 'A1', 'B', 'C'])
df1.set_index(['user'], inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=['index', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
df2.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)
```

How I can multiply between corresponding columns of `df1` and `df2.loc['denom']` for each row of `df1` and sum the rows.

```
      A   A1   B   C
user                
aaa   1  110   2   0
bbb   0  123  10  11
ccc   0  134   1   2
ddd   1  333   2   3
eee   1  444   2   0


           A     B    C
index                  
Average  0.1  0.20  0.3
Mean     0.5  0.50  0.5
denom    0.3  0.35  0.4
```

That the result will look something like:

```
      result
user                
aaa   1*0.3+2*0.35+0*0.4 
bbb   0*0.3+10*0.35+11*0.4  
ccc   0*0.3+1*0.35+2*0.4   
ddd   1*0.3+2*0.35+3*0.4 
eee   1*0.3+2*0.35+0*0.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Well that's basically a dot-product. So, one way would be -

```
df1[df2.columns].dot(df2.loc['denom'])
```

Sample run -

```
In [55]: df1
Out[55]: 
      A   A1   B   C
user                
aaa   1  110   2   0
bbb   0  123  10  11
ccc   0  134   1   2
ddd   1  333   2   3
eee   1  444   2   0

In [56]: df2
Out[56]: 
           A     B    C
index                  
Average  0.1  0.20  0.3
Mean     0.5  0.50  0.5
denom    0.3  0.35  0.4

In [57]: df1[df2.columns].dot(df2.loc['denom'])
Out[57]: 
user
aaa    1.00
bbb    7.90
ccc    1.15
ddd    2.20
eee    1.00
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, multiplying a series (`df2.loc['denom']`) with a DataFrame (`df1`) will match the series elements to the columns, so do what you want:

```
In [74]: df1 * df2.loc['denom']
Out[74]:
        A  A1     B    C
user
aaa   0.3 NaN  0.70  0.0
bbb   0.0 NaN  3.50  4.4
ccc   0.0 NaN  0.35  0.8
ddd   0.3 NaN  0.70  1.2
eee   0.3 NaN  0.70  0.0
```

(a more explicit version of the above would be: `df1.mul(df2.loc['denom'], axis=1)`)
To end with the desired result, you can then sum the above over the different columns:

```
In [75]: (df1 * df2.loc['denom']).sum(axis=1)
Out[75]:
user
aaa    1.00
bbb    7.90
ccc    1.15
ddd    2.20
eee    1.00
dtype: float64
```